# Prove convergence or Divergence of $\sum_{n=100}^{\infty} (n \log (n) \log \log (n)(\log\log\log(n))^p)^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove convergence or divergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=100}^{\infty} (n \log (n) \log \log (n)(\log\log\log(n))^p)^{-1}.$$
I have a feeling that I need to use the Cauchy Condensation Test, but I'm not sure how to work it out in this case.

Comment: You have to apply the test to the "condensed" series, again (and again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the integral test. The series converges if the integral
$$\int_{100}^\infty\frac{\mathrm d x}{x(\log x)(\log\log x)(\log\log\log x)^{p}}$$ converges.

Now, by substitution, if $p\ne 1$, this integral is equal to
$$-\frac 1{(p-1)(\log\log\log x)^{p-1}}\biggm\vert_{100}^\infty=\begin{cases}\dfrac1{(p-1)(\log\log\log 100)^{p-1}}&\text{if }p>1,\\ +\infty&\text{if }p<1.\end{cases}$$

If $p=1$, the integral diverges, as it is equal to:
$$\log\log\log\log x\biggm\vert_{100}^\infty=+\infty.$$